# Rest php api trying to Insert data into database from android app

Tags: php, database, insert

Here I am trying to insert data into database using rest api from andriod app. I am getting 200 success from server when i am trying to insert it. Please help me with this. I never did this before what i am aware of php and all. The only problem is in what variable and what type of it is sending and how to extract it in php file to insert that. Here is What code i am using both android and php.

```
private class SingupAsyn extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
URL url;
HttpURLConnection connection;
OutputStream outputStream;
OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter;
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    /*
        Receive data which is input by user
     */

    String cname = params[0];
    String cemail = params[1];
    String cuname = params[2];
    String dcpassword = params[3];
    String cdob = params[4];
    String cgender = params[5];
    try {
        url = new URL("here url");             
       connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");



  JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.accumulate("user_full_name", cname);
        jsonObject.accumulate("user_email", cemail);
        jsonObject.accumulate("user_name", cuname);
        jsonObject.accumulate("user_password", dcpassword);
        jsonObject.accumulate("user_dob", cdob);
        jsonObject.accumulate("user_gender", cgender);
        outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();
        outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);
        outputStreamWriter.write(jsonObject.toString());
        outputStreamWriter.flush();
        outputStreamWriter.close();
        Log.d("YOUR DATA", "" + jsonObject);
        Log.v( "postURL: " ,""+url);
   int res = connection.getResponseCode();
         return ("" + res);

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}



 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    Log.d("ok", s);
    int s1 = Integer.parseInt(s);
    if ((s1== HttpURLConnection.HTTP_ACCEPTED) || (s1 ==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)) {          
        pDialog.dismiss();             
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Registration Success" + s,          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } 
    else 
         {     
           pDialog.dismiss();
           Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "failure" + s,  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
        super.onPostExecute(s);
   }
}
```

This is my server side code

```
<?php
include('../db.php');
$response = array();    
$user_info = json_decode($jsonObject, true);
 if (isset($user_info['user_full_name']) && isset($user_info['user_email']) &&    isset($user_info['user_name'])) { 
$query =  mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` (user_pk, user_full_name,  user_email, user_name, user_password, user_dob, user_gender, user_status, user_ip, user_activation,  user_created_at) 
VALUES ('', '".$user_info['user_full_name']."',  '".$user_info['user_email']."',  '".$user_info['user_name']."','".$user_info['user_password']."', '".$user_info['user_dob']."',  '".$user_info['user_gender']."',  '0',  '".$_SREVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."', '".rand(10000, 99999)."', '".now()."', ") or die(mysql_error());

if ($result) {  
       $response["success_msg"] = 1;  
       $response["message"] = "Successfully Registred.";  
       echo json_encode($response);  
 } 
 else {  
       // failed to insert row  
       $response["success_msg "] = 0;  
       $response["message"] = "Your Registration is failed Please try again.";  
       // echoing JSON response  
       echo json_encode($response);  
}  

 }
 mysql_close($con);

 ?>
```

Here database.php(db.php)

```
 <?php
$dbname = 'maxximpu_tiffmiff';
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'maxximpu_tiff', 'tiffmiff123');
if (!$con) {
echo 'Could not connect to mysql';
exit;
}
mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to do is to steer clear from `mysql_*` functions in PHP, because they can be groselly insecure, and to top it all of, they have been deprecated for nearly a decade now, and are removed in newer versions of PHP.

I would suggest you do this with PDO, and prepared statements, to take care of possible SQL injection attempts. Find an example bellow on how to do this.

```php
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
// set the PDO error mode to exception
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// prepare sql and bind parameters
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO MyTable (col1, col2, col3) 
VALUES (:col1, :col2, :col3)");
$stmt->bindParam(':col1', $val1);
$stmt->bindParam(':col2', $val2);
$stmt->bindParam(':col3', $val2);

// insert a row
$val1 = "Value 1";
$val2 = "Value 2";
$val3 = "Value 3";
$stmt->execute();
```

So that we go this out of the way, lets move on to your server side script. Since you are saying you are getting a proper response but no new data in the database, means that there are some errors/warnings/notices happening in PHP but you are suppressing them, so first thing to do is enable error reporting and error display. You can do this in the script itself by adding two simple commands at the top of your script:

```php
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Just be sure to remove this before you deploy to production.

Now, if I apply my minimal knowledge of Java, you are sending that JSON object as HTTP body, so you will have to read and decode it with PHP first. To do this PHP provides a read-only stream **php://input** from which you can read as it is a file on a filesystem.

```php
$jsonObject = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

You can read more about this here, [PHP manual entry on I/O streams<sup>*docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php):

> *php://input* is a read-only stream that allows you to read raw data
>   from the request body. In the case of POST requests, it is preferable
>   to use *php://input* instead of `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` as it does not
>   depend on special php.ini directives. Moreover, for those cases where
>   `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` is not populated by default, it is a potentially
>   less memory intensive alternative to activating
>   always_populate_raw_post_data. *php://input* is not available with
>   enctype="multipart/form-data".

Comment: Thank You very much for your help just let me know what is the variable name and what  variable android api is sending and how to extract it in signup.php i am php developer. and i am not aware of android.. I just to Know about php code how to write it for inputs..  please send me a example if possible.

Comment: If you replace your *json_decode* line with mine, you should be ok.